# Use of と at end of a sentence

Tags: meaning, usage, particles, particle-と

> 白い彫像が落ちているのだと思った.
> プールの守り神みたいなものが、鎮座しているんだと

Would I be correct in interpreting this と as something along the lines as というように? So the sentence would mean something like "In a way to suggest something like a god of the pool is enshrined."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy:

> プールの守り神みたいなものが、鎮座しているんだと（思った）

So the second appearance of 思った is omitted, because it is obvious.

Or if you like,

> "白い彫像が落ちているのだ", I thought, "プールの守り神みたいなものが、鎮座しているんだ"

Because the rhetorical vibe is somewhat alike.